# statsmodels - create model from params

Tags: statsmodels

I am trying to create an empty model from params saved from a previously trained model, but the constructor stubbornly wants me to provide both endogenous and exogenous variables, which I don't have. Is there any way to get around this?

For example, I only want to do:

```
logit = sm.Logit()
pred = logit.predict(params, X)
```

But the first line won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not supported in statsmodels. Models are always associated with data.

However, for the usecase of prediction, it is possible to pickle the model and optionally delete all full length arrays including the data from the model instance and from the results instance before pickling. This doesn't work with formulas.

On the other hand, since this is Python, there might be several ways how to cheat, at your own risk.

It would be helpful if you open a issue on github https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues with a description of your usecase, and it might be possible to get the relevant features into a future version.

Comment: How do I pickle the model?

Comment: You can use the `save` method or use python's pickling directly http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.LogitResults.save.html  There is also a classmethod `load`